# Google API OAuth When User Gives Approval From App Access Control

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I'm currently building a web application that works with the Gmail API. I'm waiting for approval from Google's security team to have a proper OAuth connection, but I noticed that users can pre-approve your application by searching within the API Controls settings by your App ID.

This setting is located in the Google Account via: Admin Panel > Security > API Controls > App Access Control.

I noticed that if a user does this before they try to connect your app it doesn't go against your 100 account limit within Google Developer Console while in beta.

My question is, could you have this as permanent solution to get around the Google OAuth application if Google never approves you? Of course, through this method the user is still giving permission, just curious if this has been done by anyone before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is allowed when all your users are Google Workspace users, and is listed under exceptions to verification requirements here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en. If your application is meant for a broad set of users, completing app verification is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is allowed when all your users are Google Workspace users, and is listed under exceptions to verification requirements here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en. If your application is meant for a broad set of users, completing app verification is necessary.

Help